# django models.py ordering using foreign field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.7

I am using django1.7 and I have two models.

One of my models I would like to specify the [ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#ordering) by a field on a foreign model. The two models are linked by a foreign key.

Here are my two example models:

```
class ObjectiveDetails(models.Model, FillableModelWithLanguageVersion):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    language_version = models.ForeignKey('LanguageVersion')
    field = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=5000)
    objective_timestamp_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    objective_timestamp_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['language_version.language_code', 'id']

class LanguageVersion(models.Model):
    """Language version selection for a user"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    language_code = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    language_code_disabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language_version_timestamp_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    language_version_timestamp_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)  # the date the language version is updated when the user changes their subscription type.
```

**I am trying to order the ObjectiveDetails by the language_code on the LanguageVersion model.**

I have tried several attempts, but I cannot get it right. I have read the docs and searched SO & Google, but could not find the correct answer,

Comment: Did you try `order_by('language_version')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add ordering by language_code to **LanguageVersion** and remove .language_code from **ObjectiveDetails**

> Each foreign key you add will
>   implicitly include all of its default orderings as well.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#ordering

your models will be like this

```
class ObjectiveDetails(models.Model, FillableModelWithLanguageVersion):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    language_version = models.ForeignKey('LanguageVersion')
    field = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=5000)
    objective_timestamp_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    objective_timestamp_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['language_version', 'id']

class LanguageVersion(models.Model):
    """Language version selection for a user"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    language_code = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    language_code_disabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language_version_timestamp_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    language_version_timestamp_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)  # the date the language version is updated when the user changes their subscription type.

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['language_code']
```

Comment: demonno, thanks that works great - I am a little embarassed I missed that.